# How to install Queue(from queue import queue) library in python3.8

Tags: queue, python-3.8

from Queue import queue

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Queue'

Answer (score 2):

On python 2 the module itself was capitalized, on python 3 at some point it got renamed to lowercase.

A compatible snippet for both python 2/3 could be:

```py
    try:
        # python 2
        from Queue import Empty
        from Queue import Queue
    except ImportError:
        # python 3
        from queue import Empty
        from queue import Queue
```

Answer (score 0):

`queue` is the name of the module, while `Queue` is a class name. You can tell so because conventionally, class names start with with a capital letter.

The syntax for importing a specific class from a module is `from MODULE import CLASS`, so in your case, it should be `from queue import Queue`. From this you can use your queue : `q = Queue()`.